# How to switch TFS server for TFS PowerShell Extension

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, tfs

How do you switch the TFS server in the TFS PowerShell Extension?

I have been using the TFS PowerShell extension for quite some time and we recently moved to a different TFS server. The extension seems to still be pointing to the old server because it gives me an error message that the collection has been stopped. I switched the Team Foundation Explorer in VS to the new server and that works fine but this TFS PowerShell extension refuses to cooperate and wants to keep pointing to the old server. How do I repoint to the new server? Is there some INI? Some CONFIG file I need to change? Some registry entry?

Comment: try clearing your cache @ C:\Users\JusttTFS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache.

Comment: @Just TFS: you should put that as the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing your cache

@ C:\Users\JusttTFS\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache